# I propose renaming tag signalr-core to asp.net-core-signalr

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, synonym-request

The [signalr-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signalr-core) tag refers to the SignalR feature in ASP.NET Core (https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR). Generally, tags for ASP.NET Core features have the form `asp.net-core-[featurename]` (see [asp.net-core-middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-middleware), [asp.net-core-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core-mvc), etc.)

I propose that the [signalr-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/signalr-core) tag should be renamed similarly to `asp.net-core-signalr`. `signalr-core` can be a synonym for this newly renamed tag.